# do Google Search provide an API for application?

Tags: java, wrapper, google-search-api

I am trying to build PC application in java, and i want to search for something on the internet.
my question is can i use Google search engine and grap the results from it ? do google provide an API for this ?

for example:
assume i want to search for "Apple" on the internet
1- i want to connect to Google search service (in some way)
2- put "Apple" as input
3- collect the search results

i hope that the results i get is the same like the results if i searched
"Apple" manually in google website

Comment: before asking this question have you try to search on google "google search api"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes Google do provide you [SEARCH API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html). You can use a RESTFUL Service to extract the search information.

Please note it comes with a restriction, only 100 free search results per day.  You can also try out [Bing Search API](http://www.bing.com/toolbox/developers/)